# How to scale indicator icons

Tags: system-tray

Anyone knows if Unity has a way to scale down all indicator icons to have the same height? This big icons are very annoying.

EXAMPLE:

[image: scale indicator icons]

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure there is not. It's up to the developer afaik.

Answer (score 2):

No, actually **they are in the same height**: 22 px. But free spaces on PNGs or SVGs make the icon look smaller.

For example, the left-side picture is the wi-fi indicator icon which have free spaces above and below. Removing those spaces make it look bigger (the right-side one), however it’s in the same height:

[image: wi-fi] [image: wifi-edited]

If you want to have smaller icons, you should manually add spaces around them in PNG/SVG files only to make them look smaller.

For example, for PNG you can:

1. open the file in GIMP (which is available on Software Center);
2. scale the image down to 18 px from Image > Scale image;
3. scale the canvas up to 22 px from Image > Canvas size (click on Center button to set your icon in the middle) – now you have 2 px free from each side;
4. save the file as PNG from File > Export;
5. replace the icon with PNG you’ve created.

Comment: Yes, I can do this. But some icons are hardcoded.. so the best alternative is to ask the developer to update them. This can take a looong time.. :(.

Comment: I guess you can replace any icon on `/usr/share/icons` or take your custom one to `~/.icons` on your home.